# SelectOneMenu inside Editable DataTable Shows ItemValue and not itemLable after select

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a Editable DataTable and one of the column is SelectOneMenu, which has userName as itemlable and id as itemValue
my Jsf Page as follows

```
<h:form styleClass="form-horizontal" id="assignIssueId">
            <p:dataTable id="dataTableId" var="issue"
                value="#{assignIssueController.issueList}" editable="true"
                editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellCars">
                <f:facet name="header">
                     Cell Editing with Click and RightClick
                 </f:facet>
                <p:ajax event="cellEdit"
                    listener="#{assignIssueController.onCellEdit}" />
                <p:column headerText="Issue Number">
                    <h:outputText value="#{issue[0]}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Issue Describtion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{issue[1]}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Issue Type">
                    <h:outputText value="#{issue[2]}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Assign To">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{issue[3]}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{assignIssueController.userId}"
                                style="width:100%">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{assignIssueController.userlist}"
                                    var="ul" itemLabel="#{ul.firstName}" itemValue="#{ul.id}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Issue Type">
                    <h:outputText value="#{issue[4]}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

The problem here is I am able to edit the selectOneMenu but after selecting value from drop dowm it shows me id of new selected user and not the name in dataTable

Comment: what do you want to show with issue[3]?

Comment: its list<users> where in one can select the user depending on issue to assign

Comment: you are supposed to set ul as itemValue, and then when you select a user you trigger an event in which you set the selected user as issue[3]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a conversion error.. 
Is it possible that either the 'id' property of the User Objects are not of the same type as the 'userID' you asign the selected value to or, that 'id' is not a primitive type or a String and therefor you would need a custom converter?

Comment: both are of type int.

Comment: ok, strange... but as you are allready using primefaces in your project, you could try it with <p:selectOneMenu>...